# Как сделать собственную страницу 404 ошибки

Tags: .htaccess, php

Как сделать собственную страницу 404 ошибки только для такого типа url: http://site/xxx/ and url: http://site/xxx.php а всем остальным стандартную

Comment: Вопрос задан некорректно. Совершенно не понятно что автор имеет ввиду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле .htaccess прописать:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.site.ru/404.php
```

А чтобы работал такой вид:

```
http://www.site.ru/404/ нужно настроить ЧПУ.
```